# How to format ouput for a specified number of characters in python

Tags: python, formatting, string-formatting

I would like to print multiple tables,

following is the line which am using to print,

```
 print ("%d\t*\t%d\t=\t%2d"%(multiplicand,i,result))
```

How to specify or pass the values such as two from a variable.

I tried something like this

```
max_len = len(maxresult)
print ("%d\t*\t%d\t=\t%" +max_len+"d"%(multiplicand,i,result))
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried to create the format String before?

```
multiplicand,i = 50,2
result= multiplicand *i
max_len = 2

format = "%d\t*\t%d\t=\t%" +str(max_len)+ "d"
print (format % (multiplicand,i,result))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `*` formatter to take the size *from the inputs*:

```
multiplicand, i = 50, 2
result= multiplicand * i
max_len = len(str(result))

format = "%d\t*\t%d\t=\t%*d"
print(format % (multiplicand, i, max_len, result))
```

The `*` length specifier in `%*d` takes the next value from the tuple as the length specifier. Note that that is a *minimum length*, not a maximum.

The `str.format()` formatting operation lets you do this with any parameter, not just the length; simply use another placeholder for the parameter you want to fill with a formatting value:

```
format = "{:d}\t*\t{:d}\t=\t{:{}d}"
print(format.format(multiplicand, i, max_len, result))
```